# Amazon Signature V2 SignatureDoesNotMatch wrong host, no query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm receiving A SignatureDoesNotMatch error with an unexpected StringToSign (..sort of implied) when manually signing according to the v2 procedure described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html

The StringToSign shows a StringToSign without the query and with a hostname that is a number in stead of `s3.amazonaws.com` in the canonical request string I've composed.

Why would this possibly happen? I see the request is quite different in the url just above the error.

Answer (score 0):

S3 does not use the same rules for the string to sign.

```
StringToSign = HTTP-VERB + "\n" +
Content-MD5 + "\n" +
Content-Type + "\n" +
Expires + "\n" +
CanonicalizedAmzHeaders +
CanonicalizedResource;
```

The number you're seeing isn't the hostname, it's the expiration time.  Content-MD5 and Content-Type are empty strings for `GET` requests. (The `\n` is still there.  Do "View Source" on the XML error -- your browser is probably hiding the blank lines.)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html